# Optimizing the relation

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I have a recurrence relation:

```
f(a,b) = f(a-1,b)+f(a-2,b-1)+f(a-1,b-1)
```

where the constraints: 1<=a<=10^9 and 1<=b<=1000. I tried using recursion to find out the values but the time complexity was very high. I also tried using a dp table but that has a high time complexity as well. Also, since a can be upto 10^9, it isn't possible to create such a large table as the space complexity will be too high and I'll get a runtime error.
I want to optimize this code so that its time complexity gets reduced. Can anyone help me to achieve this? I mean which data structure to use or what algorithm should I implement to achieve this?

Comment: That small edit drastically changes the answer. Now the relation has dependence on `b`, which makes it much harder to solve

Comment: I don't even know where to begin with the `b-2`. Mathematica can't help me here

Comment: Are you sure that it's right now?

Comment: Yes. That's correct 100%. Thank you for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

This is a better question for [CS StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) by the way. Since your variables are bounded (particularly `b`), we can treat `f(a, b)` as taking only one number `n`, defined by `n=1000*a+b`. Then `a=n/1000` and `b=n%1000`. Define a new function `g(n)=f(a, b)` based on this reduction. Then we have

`g(n) = g(n-1000) + g(n-2001) + g(n-1001)`

Using the standard linear recurrence formula, we get

`g(n) = A*p^n + B*q^n + C*r^n`

where `p`, `q`, and `r` are the real solutions to the equation `x^2001-x^1001-x^1000-1=0`. You would then solve for `A`, `B`, and `C` from initial conditions (i.e. values of `f(a, b)` when `a` and `b` are small). Then you will have an explicit formula with no need for recursion. Note that the polynomial is not very numerically stable, so you need to be careful in finding the roots.